# Auto-save checkboxes node

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, express, autosave

I want to auto-save the form when the user selects a checkbox on or off. I was thinking of using an onchange to fire every time one is clicked but that seemed a bit much to write out considering there are over 150 checkboxes on my page and I need it to fire for each individual one.

My code for the check boxes is:

```
<div class="form-check">
 <label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
  setting a
 </label> 
</div>
```

I have not added the values in yet but they will be something like `{{ user.settings.a.aa }}`

What is the best method of doing this? I have looked around online and am not sure which method(s) are considered good and proper.

Comment: Perhaps use event delegation so that you'd only need a single listener for all of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

First, I guess you should have a way to identify each checkbox in your HTML. A good option would be a different `id` attribute for each one (and you can also use that to create a `for` attribute for the corresponding `label`)...

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label for="settinga" class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" id="settinga" type="checkbox" value="">
    setting a
  </label> 
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <label for="settingb" class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" id="settingb" type="checkbox" value="">
    setting b
  </label> 
</div>
...........
```

Then you'll only need to generate one onchange event to handle all. When is fired, make an ajax call to your `node.js` or `express.js` backend file, sending the checkbox identifier and the value as parameters, so it can record the change...

```
$('input.form-check-input').change(function() {

    var chkid = $(this).attr(id),
        chkvalue = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/backend/recordcheckboxchange.js',
        data: { id: chkid, value: chkvalue },
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            // Your backend file can return a JSON with the result,
            // so you can alert in case of error. For example...
            if (data.result)
                alert('ERROR: Fail changing the checkbox value');
        }
    });
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try to implement this in the morning. I am wondering what an express route would look like if the model would be found under /models/user.js then user.settings.it.settinga